# How is \$ being interpreted by grep?

Tags: command-line, unix, grep, regex, syntax

When I write

```
$ grep \$
```

then whatever I type on terminal, is matched and printed on terminal. How is `\$` being interpreted?

Answer (score 18):

The *shell* is interpreting the `\$` and passing it through to grep as `$`, the end of line character. So assuming your line has an end, it will match :-)

If you want to match an actual `$` in grep, use one of:

```
grep \\\$
grep '\$'
```

In the former, the shell interprets `\\` as `\` and `\$` as `$`, giving `\$`. In the latter, it doesn't interpret it at all.

---

As to your question as to why `\$` matches the dollar sign rather the the two-character sequence, regular expressions like those used in `grep` use special characters for some purposes. Some of those are:

```
$       end of line
^       start of line
.       any character
+       1 or more of the preceeding pattern
*       0 or more of the preceeding pattern
{n,m}   between n and m of the preceeding pattern
[x-y]   any character between x and y (such as [0-9] for a digit).
```

along with many others.

When you want to match a literla character that's normally treated as a special character, you need to escape it so that `grep` will treat it as the normal character.

Comment: to test what grep sees, try `echo \$` and then `echo \\$`

Comment: In grep \\\$, as you said, \$ is passed to grep so it should match
strings which contain \$, but why is it matching those string which 
only contain a $ ?

Comment: Because $ in grep means an end of line. To match the character $, you need to escape it so grep doesn't treat it specially. See my update.

Comment: @Pasi: echo does its own unescaping, depending on whether it's a shell builtin or not, POSIX compliant or not, etc. Better is (IMHO) to use `ls \$` and see that we get "ls: $: No such file or directory", to see that \$ is unescaped to $ but \\$ is unescaped to \$, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

The shell first expands any escape sequences before passing the arguments to the program, so it interprets the `\$` as an escape sequence and passes the single argument `$` to `grep`, which matches the end of line.  Since every line has an end, then any line should match :)

Comment: But How $ is end of line ? Isn't the end of line is \n ?

Comment: @Happy Mithal: See `man grep`; it has been decided that `$` matches the end of the line, regardless of whether or not the lines are separated by `\n`, `\r`, both, or something entirely different. In the general case, regular expressions can be used to match any string, not just a “line”, and `$` is used to match the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

It's being interpreted as the end-of-line metacharacter. If you want to match an actual dollar sign, do

```
 $ grep \\$
```

or

```
 $ grep '\$'
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` is for start of string, and `$` for end.

```
grep \$
```

or

```
grep $
```

will match every string, so anything you type is echoed back.

Try

```
grep a$
```

Now, **only strings whose last character is `a` will be matched and echoed**.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the trouble of escaping if you want to search for a literal `$`, by using the regular expression for the character class. For example,

```
$ grep '[$]' file
```